# Analytic solution for equation $4x^2y(x^2y-x+1)=15x^2+2x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, factoring

Is there an analytic solution for equation $4x^2y(x^2y-x+1)=15x^2+2x-1$?

The integer solutions can be found by reasoning; clearly we mus t have:

$15x^2+2x-1=4 k$

$\Delta'=1+15(1+4k)=16+60 k= t^2$

$(t-4)(t+4)= 3 k \times 20$

$t+4=20$ ⇒ $t=16$

⇒ $3k=16-4=12$ ⇒ $k=4$

⇒ $x= 1$

Putting in equation we get $y=2$

Can these type of equations have analytic solutions, especially when we want all solutions in $\mathbb {R}$?

Comment: It's a quadratic equation in $y$, so wouldn't the quadratic formula give you everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$4x^2y(x^2y-x+1)-15x^2-2x+1=4x^4y^2-4x^3y+4x^2y-(5x-1)(3x+1)=$$
$$4x^4y^2-2x^2y(5x-1-(3x+1))-(5x-1)(3x+1)=(2x^2y-5x+1)(2x^2y+3x+1).$$
Can you end it now?